# Row wise Operation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have to table like

| Id | Stage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Contacted |
| 2 | Won |
| 3 | Negotiation |
| 4 | Won |
| 5 | Contacted |
| 6 | Contacted |
| 8 | Negotiation |
| 9 | Negotiation |
| 10 | Contacted |

I need to get the output as

| Stage | Count | Ratio (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contacted | 4 | 100 |
| Negotiation | 3 | 75 |
| Won | 2 | 66.67 |

The order of stages Contacted, Negotiation, and Won.

And is it possible to get the Conversion ratio from stage to stage by setting the order?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You want aggregation with `lag()`.  The trick is the ordering.  For customer ordering in MySQL, `field()` is handy:

```
select state, count(*),
       (count(*) * 100 /
        lag(count(*), 1, count(*)) over (order by field(state, 'Contacted', 'Negotiation', 'Won'))
       )
from t
group by state;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7347a93978e7ae77542ef78e793abd72) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  Your stages happen to be in alphabetical order, so you can just use:

```
select state, count(*),
       (count(*) * 100 /
        lag(count(*), 1, count(*)) over (order by state)
       )
from t
group by state;
```

However, assuming an alphabetical ordering is not very generalizable.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without using the lag function?

Comment: @user12490809 . . . Yes, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I can't use this lag function in my application

Comment: Why not?  It has been part of MySQL for years.

Comment: I'm using a business intelligence tool where we can generate reports by using SQL